# Customize JMSMessageID for JMS Message not working

Tags: jmstemplate

I am trying to customize the JMSMessageID before pushing to Azure Queue, for some reason, this id is not getting into the queue instead i am seeing a random ID generated against MessageID. When i debug the code, i could see the messageID has been set properly until the MessageProducer.send(message) is called. We are using spring framework JMSTemplate. Can someone help?

```
 jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
 public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
    message.setText(message);
    message.setJMSMessageID("ID:" + "MessageId + "1");
    System.out.println("Message Id: " + message.getJMSMessageID()); 
    return message;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is illegal regarding the JMS specs,`"JMSMessageID"` can not be changed/set.

From the javadoc:

```
void setJMSMessageID(String id)throws JMSException
    Sets the message ID.

    This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. 
    This message cannot be used by clients to configure the message ID. 
    This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.
```

Reference from the API javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSMessageID-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2):

Some JMS Message header properties are set by the JMS Broker, not by the client application. For example JMSTimestamp and JMSMessageID. The JMS Broker itself ensures that this ID is unique so it makes sense you can't control it in your client application. It will be overwritte by the JMS Broker once it handles it and figures out a unique ID.

If you want to assign an ID to your message, use the JMSCorrelationID header property.